# How to use the import feature of SVN using ant+groovy

Tags: svn, ant, groovy

I need to implement automatic exporting/importing to SVN. Our team chose Groovy + Ant + SVN to implement that.

For the exporting feature, we implemented it like this:

```java
void export(src_url, dest_path) {
  ant.svn(refid: "svnSetting") {
    export(srcUrl: "${src_url}", destPath: "${dest_path}")
  }
}
```

In this way, we can export `src_url` to a local `dest_path`.

Now for the importing feature:

```java
void imports(src_url, file_path) {
  ant.svn(refid: "svnSetting") {
    import(srcUrl: "${src_url}", destPath: "${dest_path}", message: "import...")
  }
}
```

But the problem is that `import` is a keyword in groovy, so this cannot be compiled successfully.

How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often with [the Builder pattern](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Builders) in Groovy, using quotes will act as an escape ([see this post](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/using-import-from-Antbuilder-td358548.html)).

I can't replicate a SVN import, but try this:

```
void imports(src_url, file_path) {
    ant.svn(refid: "svnSetting") {
        "import"(srcUrl: "${src_url}", destPath: "${dest_path}", message: "import...")
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, yeah! It works. Really cool. Thank you Michael. What is this grammar called? Do you have some document about this?

Comment: I've added a link. You can use the Builder style markup for HTML, XML, Swing, and others. Though they use different objects, the syntax is similar.